# Fedora 34 can't install the boot loader configuration

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, boot-loader

The Error is:
**"The following error occurred while installing the boot loader. The system will not be bootable."**

I  have a problem installing Fedora 34, every time it tries to install the boot loader, this window appears. I don't know what to do. Please Help

I am trying to install Fedora 34 alongside my Windows 10 partition, and UEFI mode.

Attached three log files:

- Anaconda.log
- Storage.log
- Program1.log
- And a photo of the Message

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yG0vGHk5gS7fhX0YxoKS7W4aFp0VHnIT?usp=sharing

**UPDATE.**
I can install Mageia and Ubuntu without a problem, I don't think the problem is my EFI partition

Comment: Is this a Mac?  It appears it can’t install EFI on an apple-formatted EFI volume.

Comment: Do Mac have UEFI Secure boot like PCs and is it on?